# boost::asio::read prevents boost:asio::write from sending data to Java Socket

Tags: java, c++, sockets, boost, boost-asio

I'am trying to send data between a C++ application and a Java application back and forth. The C++ program is the client and the java program is the server. Sending the request from the client to the server works, but not the other way round.

When I use `boost::asio::read` after `boost::asio::write` to wait for the response of the server the data sent before via write is not received by the server and the client blocks at read). If I uncomment the `boost::asio::read` command sending works.

**Here are the important parts of the C++ client class:**

Connection establishing:

```
_socket = new tcp::socket(_io_service);
tcp::no_delay option(true);
tcp::resolver resolver(_io_service);
boost::asio::connect(*_socket, resolver.resolve({_host, _port}));
_socket->set_option(option);
```

First writing and then reading to socket:

```
// Send length of the query
uint32_t length = message.size();
boost::asio::write(*_socket, boost::asio::buffer(&length, 4));

// Now send the message
const char *messageBuffer = message.c_str();
size_t messageBufferLength = std::strlen(messageBuffer);
boost::asio::write(*_socket, boost::asio::buffer(messageBuffer, messageBufferLength));

// Receive length of answer
uint32_t lengthAnswer = 0;
boost::asio::read(*_socket, boost::asio::buffer(&lengthAnswer, 4));
```

**And on the Java server side:**

Connection is established via Socket (Coming from ServerSocket.accept() ). Then a DataInputStream and a DataOutputStream is opened:

```
this.dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
this.dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
```

All the reading is bases on this method, the rest ist just conversion etc.:

```
private byte[] readBytes(int n) throws IOException {
    byte[] data = new byte[n];
    dis.readFully(data);
    return data;
}
```

Do I do something wrong? It's really strange that it works without the boost::read().

Comment: Easiest way to debug such problems - is to use combination of syscall tracer(strace, ktrace, dtrace) plus network sniffer(tcpdump, wireshark, etc.). The first one will show what dialog to OS happens actually behind the abstraction scene of frameworks and second one will show you what happens actually at the network layer. You can compare two scenarios and see difference between syscalls and between packets in the network.

Comment: It appears to be a strange side effect of the software that this code is embedded in. A standalone client works as expected. I didn't find the reason yet. Something prevents the socket to send out the data from the buffer.

Comment: @Guillermo In that case i would suggest to either edit the question or answer this one yourself and ask a new one mentioning the software the code is embedded in. As is people on the slow boost-asio tag will see an unanswered question and likely read all of your code carefully to see whats wrong *before* they notice your comment, stating that the code on its own does work. At least that might happen ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the code itself works fine. I have tried it outside the surrounding software - so it somehow has to be a problem within that software.